# Validate row length when importing a txt file with fix length columns in SSIS 2016

Tags: text, import, ssis

I have a fixed length file that I have to read and validate.  That file is produced by another system, but sometimes, employees are making manual changes to it.  Example:

Layout

Variable: Surname          size:  30   1 -30
Variable: Name             size:  30   31-60
Variable: Email            size:  30   61-90
Variable: Comments         size:  30   91-120
Variable: CarriageReturn   size:   2  121-123

So the system produces the following text file:
[Source file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjFcM.jpg)

But then there is a manual intervention and the person does not respect the column length:
[Source file after manual intervention](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcTNy.jpg)

So before even starting to validate the values in the columns, everything is offset because my first carriage return is now splitting my "Comments" column when I read it in the SSIS.

Is there a way to tell the system that, if the length row is more than 2033, output in error file and continue ?  What is the best way to do this?

Mylene

Answer (score 0):

I found it!!

```
//Pass the file path and file name to the StreamReader and StreamWriter constructors
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(inputFile);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Dts.Connections["CE802CleanInput"].ConnectionString);
            StreamWriter swe = new StreamWriter(Dts.Connections["CE802PreValidationErrors"].ConnectionString);

            //Read the first line
            line = sr.ReadLine();

            while (line != null)
            {
               int length = line.Length;
               if (length > 2033)
               {
                    if 
                    {
                        swe.WriteLine("Some records have been rejected at the pre validation phase.");
                        swe.WriteLine("Those records will not be included in the process.");
                        swe.WriteLine("Please review the records below, fix and re submit if applicable.");
                        swe.WriteLine("Input file: " + Dts.Connections["CE802Input"].ConnectionString.ToString());
                        swe.WriteLine();
                        swe.WriteLine(line);
                        count++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        swe.WriteLine(line);
                        count++;
                    }
               }
               if (length <= 2033)
               {
                    sw.WriteLine(line);
               }
                line = sr.ReadLine(); 
            }
```